# Using IpcChannel and Remote PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, remoting

I have an application using Remoting and IpcChannel to access an object shared between processes : it allows me to access the same object in my application and in PowerShell, where I can send custom Cmdlet to my application.

This works perfectly fine when I use PowerShell on the same machine, but I encounter a problem when trying to use the Cmdlet in RemotePowerShell :

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Failed to create an IPC Port: Access is denied.
```

My IpcChannel is created with these properties :

```
IDictionary properties = new HashTable();
properties["portName"] = "MyApp";
["authorizedGroup"] = account;//the "Everyone" group
```

I thought about an access right related issue but I use the same domain account, which is local administrator on the two machines. I also tried changing the "authorizedGroup" property and disabling any form of security on the IpcChannel, without any success.

I'm running short on ideas and the exception message is not of much help.

Does anybody have any clue where this might come from ?

Comment: An IpcChannel can only be used to communicate between processes running on the same machine http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b3scst2(v=vs.100).aspx.

Comment: I thought this might be possible by using PowerShell. Thanks for the clarification.